# Web API Folder to place template Reports (rpt, xml, etc.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports

I have my Web API project, and one its controllers will generate Reports on the fly (PDF, Excel, etc.)

In order to generate the Reports, I have the template files rpt (crystal reports), xml (componentone), etc. My question is where is the recommended folder to place those files.

Note. The generated report won't be saved on server, the controller will just response the stream to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put them into "~/Content/Reports" and read from there.